# Adding an HTML template to WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to add an HTML template to WordPress, without PHP? A client sent me a template with only HTML, JavaScript and CSS to migrate it to his WordPress account, but as far as I know it is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add an html template to wordpress, without php?

Technically, **yes**. The [WordPress Codex page for *Theme Development*§Basic Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates) mentions:

> At the very minimum, a WordPress Theme consists of two files:
>
> - style.css
> - index.php

*Technically* speaking, you could re-name your `index.html` template file to `index.php` and include a `style.css` file that's conformant to the WordPress spec to include the requisite theme metadata in the [*stylesheet header*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet). That in itself would be installable into WordPress and usable as a Theme.

However your implication that this wouldn't be particularly helpful is also correct, because none of the dynamic content that WordPress would be used for would be pulled through and displayed out of the box – the template itself isn't written to leverage the proper PHP methods to pull this data in the first place. Your client is likely undereducated, misinformed, or otherwise confused on the wide gulf of fundamental difference between a standard website template and one that will work well with (or is specifically created for use with) WordPress.

Your client's implied expectation may be for you to update it into something that *would* be useful to use in a WordPress environment (which is most certainly possible, albeit likely arduous and time-intensive depending on the specific requirements), but interpreting communications between you and your client is much outside the scope of Stack Overflow.